# Use of unassigned variable in C# 10

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Consider the following code under .NET 6, C# 10:

```
bool isAggregate;
var exception = new Exception();
if (isAggregate = exception is AggregateException aggregateException)
{
    foreach (var innerException in aggregateException.InnerExceptions)
    {
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that `aggregateException` is unassigned here. I would think that this way of declaring a variable name within a condition should have worked. Is this a corner case or am I missing something?

Removing the assignment expression from the condition seems to work just fine:

```
if (exception is AggregateException aggregateException)
```

**EDIT:** Another odd case as I was trying to get used to new language features:

```
public Error (Exception exception)
{
    if (exception.InnerException is null innerException) // Error.
    {
    }
}
```

I have gotten used to `if (int.TryParse("0", out var i)) { }` so was surprised that there wasn't a concise way to declare variables inline this way.

[image: Error 1:]

[image: Error 2:]

Comment: I think this is just a limitation in the definite assignment analysis. This was improved in C# 10: have you checked with that? If not, check whether there's an open issue in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions

Comment: I think it's a corner case, since it's roughly equivalent to `isAggregate = exception is AggregateException aggregateException; if (isAggregate)`.

Comment: Interesting, it's the `isAggregate = ` bit that is confusing the compiler. Remove that and it works fine. You really should remove it since it serves no purpose. If you really need the `isAggregate` value, then set it inside the `if` manually.

Comment: It looks like [C# 10's improvements to definite assignment analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-10.0/improved-definite-assignment.md) don't cover this case, unfortunately

Comment: `var Exception innerException` - use either `var innerException` (to let the compiler figure out the exact type) OR `Exception innerException` to explicitly specify a type to cast every inner exception to. Or is this the result of a tool like Resharper documenting the real type of "var"?